# ag-grid default behavior for an angular application

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

is there any way to set the default properties/attributes for all  `<ag-grid-angular>` in an angular application?

most of this example (first group) are same on all instacne in my application,
and the properties/atttributes required in both sides (`template.html/ component.ts`)

I am search for a configuration change the default of all instances.

```
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [modules]="modules"
        [animateRows]="true"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [localeText]="localeText"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [statusBar]="statusBar"
        [rowModelType]="rowModelType"


        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
       ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Grid Options`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-options) interface for that. With this, you can create some default options and then just add needed properties per usage. For example:

```html
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
<ag-grid-angular>
```

```js
const DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS: GridOptions = {
  animatedRows: true
}

...
class Component {
  public gridOptions: GridOptions = {...DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS, rowData: myData};
}
```

You can learn more in [the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-interface).

Comment: is there a way to bind angular attribute to global static object, somthing like `[gridOptions]="global.static_gridOptions"`

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You could write your custom directive that matches all ag-grid-angular components and assigns default value, but that can be problematic in further customization.